# How to autoplay super slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I recently choose superslider from this [link](http://www.jqueryscript.net/slider/Full-Screen-Slider-Plugin-Superslides.html)
then config it on my website and it's worked absolutely . but I have a problem with it. :( I can't start auto play for this slider. due to its documentation on mentioned link there are some options that I can use for start auto play but I don't know how and there is no auto play demo to show me how ?
This is my code :

```
<section id="slider">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
          <div class="slider_area">
            <!-- Start super slider -->
            <div id="slides">
              <ul class="slides-container">                          
                <li>
                  <img src="img/slider/2.jpg" alt="img">
                   <div class="slider_caption">
                    <h2>Title</h2>
                    <p>Description</p>
                    <a class="slider_btn" href="#">More</a>
                  </div>
                  </li>
                <!-- Start single slider-->
                <li>
                  <img src="img/slider/3.jpg" alt="img">
                   <div class="slider_caption slider_right_caption">
                       <h2>Title</h2>
                       <p>Description</p>
                       <a class="slider_btn" href="#">More</a>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <!-- Start single slider-->
                <li>
                  <img src="img/slider/4.jpg" alt="img">
                   <div class="slider_caption">
                       <h2>Title</h2>
                       <p>Description</p>
                       <a class="slider_btn" href="#">More</a>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <nav class="slides-navigation">
                <a href="#" class="next"></a>
                <a href="#" class="prev"></a>
              </nav>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

now how can I use this option to auto play slider

```
$('#slides').superslides(options_hash)

delay: 5000
play: true
slide_speed: 'normal'
slide_easing: 'linear'
nav_class: 'slides-navigation'
container_class: 'slides-container'
pagination: true
hashchange: true
```

thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 4):

Use `play: 1000` for a 1000-millisecond delay between autoloading slides. Use `false` to disable, but a number to enable.

Here is an example that autoplays the slides and stops the autoplay on hover:

```
 $(function() {
  $('#slides').superslides({
    hashchange: true,
    play: 2000
  });
  $('#slides').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).superslides('stop');
    console.log('Stopped')
  });
  $('#slides').on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).superslides('start');
    console.log('Started')
  });
});
```

No hover effect:

```
$(function() {
  $('#slides').superslides({
    hashchange: true,
    play: 2000
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks but your code has some problem . the trigger works only on mouse enter and leave. I want to only auto play every for example 2 seconds  . and can't handle it :(

Comment: Just remove the mouseenter and mouseleave segments if you do not need the cursor interaction.

Comment: I already try that . but its very strange and  and doesn't work :(

Comment: Anything in the console perhaps?

Comment: yes there are some errors like failed to load http://localhost:28112/css/queryLoader.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) and some png and gif .

Answer (score 1):

looks like there is more documentation here: https://github.com/nicinabox/superslides

perhaps call `$('#slides').superslides('start')` on load

Comment: thanks but there is no document for simple auto play :(